# Android&Firebase | Row too big to fit into CursorWindow while adding data to Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **Firebase's Firestore** to save my data class for the Android project. 
I followed the official tutorial's *add Data* section provided by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment)

but now get the error as followed:

#### SQLiteQuery Exception

> E/SQLiteQuery: exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=9; query: SELECT overlay_mutation, largest_batch_id FROM document_overlays WHERE uid = ? AND collection_path = ? AND largest_batch_id > ?

Below are my Data Class to save, and the function to make it as `HashMap`.

#### Diary.kt

```
data class Diary(
    val id: String = "",
    val account: String = "",
    val title: String = "",
    val content: String = "",
    val imageUri: String? = null,
    val likesCount: Int = 0,
    val isLiked: Boolean = false,
    val comments: List<String> = listOf(),
    val createdTime: Long = 0L,
    val updatedTime: Long? = null,
    val isThumbnailExist: Boolean = false
) {
    fun mappingForFireStore(): HashMap<String, Any?> {
        return hashMapOf(
            "id" to id,
            "account" to account,
            "title" to title,
            "content" to content,
            "imageUri" to imageUri,
            "likes_count" to likesCount,
            "is_liked" to isLiked,
            "comments" to comments,
            "created_time" to createdTime,
            "updated_time" to updatedTime,
            "is_thumbnail_exist" to isThumbnailExist
        )
    }
}
```

Here is a function that I called to save it to FireStore.

#### Save-To-FireStore func.kt

```
private fun asyncTestFirebase() {
    val data1 = Diary(
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        account = idInput.value!!.trim(),
        title = "My second data",
        content = "test data.",
        createdTime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).time.time
    ).mappingForFireStore()

    db.collection("diaries")
        .add(data1)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
            Log.d("Haha", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { error ->
            Log.d("OMG", error.stackTraceToString())
        }
}
```

I have searched for similar questions, but could not find answers fit as I am not trying to store any images directly, or using `Cursor` or `Field`. I don't think the data weighs more than 1mb so its size would not be a matter.

How can I successfully save data to Firestore in this case?

Below is `AndroidRuntimeException` Log, just in case.

Thank you.

#### AndroidRuntime Error Log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.movingroot.simpleproject, PID: 1616
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.2).
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:539)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=9
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:330)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=9
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:1003)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:145)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:238)
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:287)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach(SQLitePersistence.java:493)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlays(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:149)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getDocumentsMatchingCollectionQuery(LocalDocumentsView.java:365)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getDocumentsMatchingQuery(LocalDocumentsView.java:266)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.QueryEngine.appendRemainingResults(QueryEngine.java:259)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.QueryEngine.performQueryUsingRemoteKeys(QueryEngine.java:175)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.QueryEngine.getDocumentsMatchingQuery(QueryEngine.java:85)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.executeQuery(LocalStore.java:844)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.initializeViewAndComputeSnapshot(SyncEngine.java:214)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.listen(SyncEngine.java:207)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.addQueryListener(EventManager.java:104)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$listen$7$com-google-firebase-firestore-core-FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java:177)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:4)

Comment: What is the exact line of code that produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo it crashes when `add(data1)` is executed.

Comment: @MovingRoot Lee please check the issue discussed on https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/364